# JSON functions - can't get all data

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I've tried to get all of data from JSON listed below, but I can't get data from 'keys' label. I work on SQL Server 2016

```
"keys": [
        "hmb sklep",
        "code1",
        "pol",
        "DESKTOP"
      ]
```

Anyone can help?

```
DECLARE @jsjsj NVARCHAR(MAX);
set @jsjsj = N'{
  "rows": [
    {
      "keys": [
        "hmb sklep",
        "code1",
        "pol",
        "DESKTOP"
      ],
      "clicks": 0.0,
      "impressions": 1.0,
      "ctr": 0.0,
      "position": 91.0
    },
    {
      "keys": [
        "sz\u00f3stka weidera",
        "code2",
        "fra",
        "DESKTOP"
      ],
      "clicks": 0.0,
      "impressions": 1.0,
      "ctr": 0.0,
      "position": 82.0
    }
  ],
  "responseAggregationType": "byPage"
}'


SELECT json1.*
FROM OPENJSON (@jsjsj, N'$.rows')
  WITH (
    ctr VARCHAR(max) '$.ctr',
    impressions VARCHAR(max) '$.impressions',
    clicks VARCHAR(max) '$.clicks',
    position VARCHAR(max) '$.position'
  ) AS json1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02pgT.png)

This is data from google search console

Comment: How do you want it returned: the whole array as JSON `["hmb sklep",...]` or in rows (how do you want to join) or what?

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.  This assumes you have a known or maximum number of keys

```
SELECT json1.*
FROM OPENJSON (@jsjsj, N'$.rows')
  WITH (
    ctr VARCHAR(max) '$.ctr',
    impressions VARCHAR(max) '$.impressions',
    clicks VARCHAR(max) '$.clicks',
    position VARCHAR(max) '$.position',
    keys0 varchar(max) '$.keys[0]',
    keys1 varchar(max) '$.keys[1]',
    keys2 varchar(max) '$.keys[2]',
    keys3 varchar(max) '$.keys[3]'
  ) AS json1
```

**Results**

[image]